# [Solidity][Metamask] Metamask no longer injects web3

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, metamask

I want to update my old javascript file that interacts with metamask and solidity. On the server it says metamask no longer injects web3? How do I change the following code for the server to request a metamask account?

```
    try {
      const web3 = await getWeb3();
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        contractABI,
        contractAddress,
      );
      var userAccount;

      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      if (accounts[0] !== userAccount) {
          userAccount = accounts[0];
      }
      
    } catch (error) {
      // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
var userAccount = accounts[0];
```

Comment: It's good to explain what this code does. Stack Overflow is not for copying+pasting answers, but for gaining knowledge, while solving problems.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/8077

Instead of web3, they inject `ethereum`. But since still some clients use `web3` w e still have to write logic to detect web3. Easier way is to use this package:

```
   npm i @metamask/detect-provider
```

It is a tiny utility for detecting the MetaMask Ethereum provider, or any provider injected at window.ethereum.

```
import detectEthereumProvider from "@metamask/detect-provider";
import Web3 from "web3";

// in react or next.js this code should be placed in useEffect
 const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
      if (provider) {
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
        // now you have the provider
        // after this you can place the logic



   try {
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        contractABI,
        contractAddress,
      );
      var userAccount;

      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      if (accounts[0] !== userAccount) {
          userAccount = accounts[0];
      }
      
    } catch (error) {
      // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
  // handle the case provider is not available
  } else {
    
    console.error("Please install Metamask");
  }
};
```